# Post page pagination not working - wordpress WP-PageNavi

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I am having trouble with wordpress post page with pagination. I have installed a pagination plugin (WP-PageNavi), and I have being able to print all my posts so far, but pagination just shows one page (the present one). How can I make pagination work properly?

```
<?php
// args query
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'order'          => 'DESC'
);

// custom query
$recent_posts = new WP_Query($args);

// check that we have results
if($recent_posts->have_posts()) : ?>

<ul class="article_list">

    <?php
    // start loop
    while ($recent_posts->have_posts() ) : $recent_posts->the_post(); ?>

    <li class="regular">
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
            <div class="text">
                <p class="category"><?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { echo $category->cat_name . ' '; } ?></p>
                <h3 class="article_title"><?php echo mb_strimwidth(get_the_title(), 0, 80, '...'); ?></h3>
                <p class="date"><?php echo get_the_date( 'Y-m-d' ); ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="mask">
                <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url();?>" alt="" class="art_img">
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif;
// reset query
wp_reset_postdata();
?>

<?php include($path.'libs/pagination.php'); ?>
```

Here is my pagination.php file:

```
<div class="pagination">
  <?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem in my code: 
I was not adding anything for the pagination in my query, so it was returning all my posts.
So I added a pagination logic to my custom query and it did work.

```
<?php   $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $custom_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'paged' => $paged
    );

// custom query
$recent_posts = new WP_Query($custom_args);

// check that we have results
if($recent_posts->have_posts()) : ?>

<ul class="article_list">

    <?php
    // start loop
    while ($recent_posts->have_posts() ) : $recent_posts->the_post(); ?>

    <li class="regular">
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
            <div class="text">
                <p class="category"><?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { echo $category->cat_name . ' '; } ?></p>
                <h3 class="article_title"><?php echo mb_strimwidth(get_the_title(), 0, 80, '...'); ?></h3>
                <p class="date"><?php echo get_the_date( 'Y-m-d' ); ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="mask">
                <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url();?>" alt="" class="art_img">
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif;
echo '<div class="pagination">';
if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(array( 'query' => $recent_posts )); }
echo '</div>';
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have put wp_pagenavi(); function to libs/pagination.php.

So, replace it with

```
wp_pagenavi(array( 'query' => $recent_posts ));
```

So, final code should look like,

```
<?php
// args query
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'order'          => 'DESC'
);

// custom query
$recent_posts = new WP_Query($args);

// check that we have results
if($recent_posts->have_posts()) : ?>

<ul class="article_list">

    <?php
    // start loop
    while ($recent_posts->have_posts() ) : $recent_posts->the_post(); ?>

    <li class="regular">
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
            <div class="text">
                <p class="category"><?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { echo $category->cat_name . ' '; } ?></p>
                <h3 class="article_title"><?php echo mb_strimwidth(get_the_title(), 0, 80, '...'); ?></h3>
                <p class="date"><?php echo get_the_date( 'Y-m-d' ); ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="mask">
                <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url();?>" alt="" class="art_img">
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif;
echo '<div class="pagination">';
if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(array( 'query' => $recent_posts )); }
echo '</div>';
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: It didn't work. To make it more clear, I have edited my question, adding the code of my pagination file.

Comment: Keep wp_pagenavi(array( 'query' => $recent_posts )); 
 unchanged, and try to move wp_reset_postdata(); after include($path.'libs/pagination.php');

Comment: sorry, I dont understand how it would look like.